# How to restrict one user to update the record while its being used by another using MVC, EF?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I've an application using MVC5 & EF6. I want to restrict one user to modify the particular record when it's being used by another user. I'm trying by all ways like concurrency in EF but, still looking for the better way. I want to **'Lock'** table records for users. So one user can not change another users record. Anybody tried?

Comment: Either you use MySQL's built-in locking functionality, or you implement your own locking mechanism. Since you are using asp.net, you probably have to implement your own locking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF implements an optimistic concurrency model. In other words, it assumes there will be no conflict and then returns an exception if there is. That usually works pretty well for programmatic updates, but is pretty lacking in the user experience department.

For example, assume two users are editing the same object simultaneously. User 1 saves first, followed by User 2. User 1 wins, of course, and they go on about their day, but now User 2 is in a predicament. It is on them, now to resolve this conflict. They can either discard their work, and start over based on the update made by User 1, or overwrite User 1's work, discarding that user's changes. If User 1's work is overwritten, there's no notification that that has occurred.

Pessimistic concurrency is far better in this scenario. The record is "locked" while User 1 edits. User 2 must wait for User 1 to finish. Only then can they edit the record. As a result, there are never conflicts that need to be resolved and no risk of one user's work being lost.

Implementing this type of concurrency is pretty straight-forward. You just need some place to record that a particular object is being edited by a particular user at a particular time. This could be on the record itself or some sort of access log. Regardless of where you put that information, you then retrieve it when a user wants to edit a record. If there's no current user editing or the lock has expired, you open the record and log the current user and time. If there is an existing user and the lock is still active, then you deny access or simply make the record read-only, so the user can view it but not edit.

Comment: This is what I expected to do. But while doing some code on this I found that we need to implement lock on each table with Pessimistic concurrency. Can we do something to achieve lock parent level & child table as well?

Comment: If it's a child object, you just walk up to the root checking that each parent along the way is not locked